# In-app Billing Error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

My [UNMANAGED] in-app purchase won't work, Before it works perfectly which I can purchase successfully using Test Accounts. But it suddenly won't work, as I remember what I did to Merchant Account is only add more 2-4 Test Accounts. Then after adding, my in-app purchase won't work. So I updated the public key and upload an Apk as draft. But still won't work.

When the app is in google play page I received a LogCat error:

```
11-20 17:00:18.840: E/Finsky(2182): [187] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramsqE9ZgJf5Z6GeZu1wwGPosw' failed!
```

Then when I click the Buy & Accept button I only received these LogCats:

```
11-20 17:00:39.520: I/BillingService(2408): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
11-20 17:00:39.520: I/LoginActivity(2408): purchase was successfully sent to server
```

I am expecting for `Security Verification's Logs` and `onPurchaseStateChange(...)` to called, but I don't get any onPurchaseStateChange.

Please help me with this problem.

Also when I test **android.test.purchased** `the reserved product IDs for testing static in-app billing responses`  but still got the same Logs/Responses.

**UPDATES-----------------------**

I removed some **Test Accounts** but leaving only two (as suggested by **@Tigger** below). And now I'm not getting any error from **Google page**. But still the **onPurchaseStateChange()** function didn't fire. And I didn't receive any Logs from **Security.java**.

The last Log I received is: **"purchase was successfully sent to server"**

Answer (score 6):

This may not be a correct answer, but from my personal testing and notes taken from all over the place:

- The *draft* app you upload **must** have the same "version code" and "version name" as any that you are testing.
- If you upload a new version (with a new "version code" or "version name") it can take 4 to 24 hours before the new version will work correctly for testing.
- Double check that the account used on the device is in fact one of the test accounts.
- Your draft APK that you upload must be signed with the same key that will be used on the final version.
- For testing on a device (the emulator will not work with the Play Store), so long as the "version code" and "version name" match the the draft APK in the Play Store, testing and debugging works.

Hope that helps a little.

*Edit*: Some changes to clarify a few points.

Comment: I met all of these requirements, the version code and version name of the draft and installed apk are the same. Draft apk was upload 1+days old. Test account is correct and set as primary in the device. Apk is signed.

Comment: My only thought is to remove all but one of the test accounts and try again. Maybe you have a high ASCII comma or a TAB between the test accounts and this is throwing things out at Google end.

Comment: I tried removing tests accounts, and now I not getting the error from Google page (11-20 17:00:18.840: E/Finsky(2182): [187] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramsqE9ZgJf5Z6GeZu1wwGPosw' failed!). But still my app won't fire the onPurchaseStateChange(). And I didn't receive a Logs from Security.java. the Debug is turned on/set to true.

Comment: @Tigger you mention that the uploaded apk must have been signed with the same keystore as the test apk. Does this mean that you can't test while running in debug mode (connected to Android Studio, hitting breakpoints along the way)? Or were you just saying that IF you're testing with an adhoc build it's gotta be signed with the same keystore?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen I use Eclipse, but the IDE should not make any difference. So long as the test APK version code and name match the draft APK copy in the Play Store, testing and debugging should work correctly - it does for me. I've also updated the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, but my mistake was that the upload behaviour has changed.

It used to be that you uploaded an APK as a draft to the production tab of the play store dashboard. Now, you have to upload to the Alpha tab of the dashboard, *and* publish your app (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps).

Don't worry if you're still in pre-production on your app; if you have no APKs in the production tab when you publish, nothing will appear in the Play Store.