# android billing v3 - onActivityResult gets not called

Tags: android, android-intent, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

When trying to buy a product it works (when I restart my app and query iab for purchased products, it counts as purchased).

The problem is, after the user clicks buy in the market gui `onActivityResult()` **does not get called**. This happens for my own products using test account aswell as it happens with static response android.test.purchased.

Instead the following **error message** appears:

> ERROR/Finsky(1374): [1] IntentUtils.createIntentForReceiver: Could not find receiver for com.ludocrazy.artisan

**Question**: what do I have to do, so the intent gets properly forwarded? i seem to have missed something in the docs - but thought to have checked everything multiple times.

to purchase i use the following:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), myRequestCode, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
```

**TL;DR**: what basically happens: is that send BUY_INTENT works, the purchaseflow (user gui) and everything works, but finsky can't find my activity and thus onActivityResult() gets not called.

---

**addendum**: if i add a class extending BroadcastReceiver, add the apropriate intent-filters to the manifest, then the error disappears and i get a ACTION_NOTY on BroadcastReceiver.onReceive().
but this does only contain the extra-string NOTIFICATION_ID, nothing else that should be coming with the intent in order for onActivityResult() to handle the purchase (e.g. the extras: RESPONSE_CODE, INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA, INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE).
so this is not a workaround.

i looked at the TrivialDriveSample from IABv3, read IabHelper and the other utility classes, read the google docs, followed all testing steps. i don't know what else tro try / check :-/

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was related to this post:

[Android Activity destroyed when it shouldn't be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761982/android-activity-destroyed-when-it-shouldnt-be)

basically the main activity gets totally destroyed to free resources (during the in app billing view) so onActivityResult() never gets called...   one possible solution could be to properly save the state of the activity, create another "light" activity which would actually be responsible to do the billing (pass the sku via Intent) and then restart the main activity. Again, this is all assuming you have the same problem and that your main activity gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

My gremlin for this problem was using a negative `requestCode`, which breaks the result dispatching mechanism.